# Fixed data at beginning of a Boost managed_mapped_file

Tags: c++, boost

I'd like to stick a bit of fixed character data onto the beginning of a Boost `managed_mapped_file` that won't interfere with the Boost memory segment manager. The hope is to use this data to determine which Boost version was used to build the file (and on which platform).

One way might be to create a specialized `basic_managed_mapped_file` that uses a different `base_t` based on `ipcdetail::managed_open_or_create_impl` with a new `m_mapped_region` based on `boost::interprocess::mapped_region` with a modified `get_address()` that would add a fixed base to the returned value. The original address could be used to store the data.  But this seems like a pretty roundabout way to do it (if it works at all) and digs far too much into Boost's guts.

My goal is to check whether the file is compatible with the current library/platform in use. Using the segment manager or the mapped objects will result in segfaults if the file is not compatible.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: What about using the file name for things.

Comment: Thought about that, it's a little less desirable than being able to annotate the file data itself somehow.